# exporting .vcf contact in mobile web app capable aka HomeScreen app

Tags: html, web-applications, safari, mobile-safari, vcf-vcard

I suspect this must be intentional on Apples part but I will ask anyway because it works from both mobile and desktop safari.

I create a simple .vcf contact from inside my web app and try to download (aka export) it.

This creates a .vcf file in desktop Safari that is actually downloaded where the user actually has to click that to get it into contacts. And in the mobile safari version (without saving to home screen), the exact same code will pop up a warning screen [mobile .vcf warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De980.png) which at least gives the user the opportunity to import the .vcf into contacts.

Admittedly neither the desktop or mobile safari use case it a good user experience but at least they work.

Whereas, the exact same code saved as a homescreen mobile app simply fails without error on an iphone (i.e 

    
)

I have tried multiple ways to export from the app (most of which work from safari mobile or desktop browsers if NOT web app capable)

1. as a blob from base64 text/vcard
2. as base64 text/vcard
3. using window.open(vcftxt); // where vcftext is base64 text/vcard
4. using location.href = vcftxt; // where vcftext is base64 text/vcard
5. using an a tag with download= and href= vcftxt url

All the above work..just not in a homescreen app that appears native

code example (run on iphone safari...not tested on android)

- https://www.airbridgelabs.com/s/0/app3.html?sd=100 -  [Click on contacts logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quQlr.png) at the bottom when [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNoLu.png) opens in safari and you will see the warning which still allows the user to open the .vcf in contacts
- https://www.airbridgelabs.com/s/0/app3.html?sd=100&tm2=100 - This will walk you thru saving to home screen or you can simply save to home screen manually without the tm2 parm. click on the contacts logo at the bottom when this page opens in safari and you will see nothing. Safari developer remote console shows no errors or warnings...simply does not work.

I figure I can probably pass the created .vcf to a page on my server which in turn opens the .vcf which will likely then export it to mobile contacts..but that is a lame solution which still requires the user to be online to save an embedded contact.

And please don't use the argument that this is about security. If it was about security then you wouldn't be allowed to do the exact same thing from a desktop page, or mobile safari page or hybrid native app...and you can. This looks like Apple simply reducing the value of mobile web apps that look native.

What I am looking for is an offline work around to simply save a mobile contact already coded into the mobile web app capable content the user intentionally created.

Comment: Facing the same issue here - curious what you ended up doing?